# how to print IP_ADDRESS:port # before sed command

Tags: bash

Is there an easy way to print the IP_Address:port# ? Because I soon as it gets to the SED command, the port :# is stripped

#### input file example

```
Apr 6 14:20:41 TCP 178.255.83.1:80 in
```

#### preferred output like this

```
Apr 6 14:20:41 TCP 178.255.83.1:80 in United Kingdom
```

```
egrep -w 'TCP|UDP' $Denied_IPs |
sed 's/:[^:]* in/ in/; s/:[^:]* out/ out/' |
awk '{cmd="echo "$5" | code | fgrep 'Country:' | cut -c 16-43";
      cmd | getline rslt;
      close(cmd);
      print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "rslt}' >> "$IP2COUNTRY"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command is stripping the port explicitly.  Given that that is all the `sed` command is doing, simply remove it from the expression.

That's a rather unoptimal implementation, by the way.  Especially after we remove the `sed`, the `egrep` can be folded into the `awk`:

```
awk '/ (TCP|UDP) / {
       split($5, addr, /:/);
       cmd = "echo " addr[1] " | code | fgrep Country: | cut -c 16-43";
       cmd | getline rslt;
       close(cmd);
       print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, rslt
     }' < "$Denied_IPs" >> "$IP2COUNTRY"
```

and I can't help but think that the invocation of `code` within `awk` can be optimized a bit.

(I also removed the single quotes around `'Country:'`, which were doing nothing useful — and if they *had* been needed, they would in fact have broken the script because the whole thing is already wrapped in single quotes.)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. the 'code' script actually takes the IP and returns its country origin, that is why I had sed in there to strip the :80 (port number) ...so there is no way to retain original format 111.222.333.444:80 before I strip it?

Comment: You'd need to strip it within the `awk` script, so you have both forms available; obviously if you're stripping the port before `awk` sees it, `awk` can never get it back.  I'll go add code for that to my example.

Comment: thanks. I'll see what I can do with your code, actually I had something similar to you split command but could neve get it working correctly, I think the egrep messed it up ..anyways, I noticed that you removed input file from your awk. Not sure why because how would it know where to search the TCP|UDP nemonics..

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo; I've restored it.

Comment: geekosaur, I'm really impressed!! I can tell you have some years under your belt, for sure. Fixing someone's code is one thing but to fix it so its to your liking and efficent is brilliant! Much appreciated.